# Antiderivative of Meijer G-function

Tags: integration, special-functions

In the python sympy CAS framework one strategy to compute integrals is to transform the integration kernel to a MeijerG-function, obtain the corresponding antiderivative as MeijerG-function and rewrite it as classical function. (More details: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/g-functions.html)

Unfortunately, in some cases the algorithm does not work quite right. (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/25786) This is a cross-post to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831298/antiderivative-of-meijer-g-function?noredirect=1#comment10284654_4831298

Is there a formula for $\int G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right) \,dz$?

For $z>0$, $c\in\mathbb R \setminus\{0\}$, $\gamma>0$ we can substitute $u:=cz^\gamma$ to get
$$\int G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right) \,dz
= \frac{1}{\gamma c^{1/\gamma}} \int G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , u\right) \, u^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}} du .$$

Then using $$ z^\rho \, G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , z \right) =  G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1+\rho , \ldots, a_n+\rho, a_{n+1}+\rho,\ldots,a_p+\rho\\ b_1+\rho,\ldots,b_m+\rho,b_{m+1}+\rho,\ldots,b_q+\rho\end{matrix} , z\right) $$ with $\rho=\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}$ and $$\int G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , z\right) \,dz =  G_{p+1,q+1}^{m,n+1}\left(\begin{matrix}1, a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,0,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , z\right) $$ and substituting back yields

$$ \int G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right) \,dz = \frac{1}{\gamma c^{1/\gamma}} G_{p+1,q+1}^{m,n+1}\left(\begin{matrix}1,a_1+\frac{1}{\gamma}, \ldots, a_n+\frac{1}{\gamma}, a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{\gamma},\ldots,a_p+\frac{1}{\gamma}\\ b_1+\frac{1}{\gamma},\ldots,b_m+\frac{1}{\gamma},0,b_{m+1}+\frac{1}{\gamma},\ldots,b_q+\frac{1}{\gamma}\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right). $$

Now, in the case of $\gamma$ positive and uneven and $G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , 0\right)=0$ the integral kernel $z\mapsto G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right)$ viewed as function over the reals is symmetric with respect to the origin. Therefore, in this case the formula extends to negative $z\in\mathbb R$ as well. For $\gamma$ positive and with even parity and again $G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , 0\right)=0$ the integral kernel as function over the reals is symmetric with respect to the y-Axis. Therefore, in this case (interpreting the right hand side as $0$ for $z=0$)

$$ \int G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right) \,dz = \frac{z/\sqrt{z^2}}{\gamma c^{1/\gamma}} G_{p+1,q+1}^{m,n+1}\left(\begin{matrix}1,a_1+\frac{1}{\gamma}, \ldots, a_n+\frac{1}{\gamma}, a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{\gamma},\ldots,a_p+\frac{1}{\gamma}\\ b_1+\frac{1}{\gamma},\ldots,b_m+\frac{1}{\gamma},0,b_{m+1}+\frac{1}{\gamma},\ldots,b_q+\frac{1}{\gamma}\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right). $$

Is it true, that in those two cases the formula is even valid for general $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$? What if $\gamma >0$ is neither an even nor uneven number but, let's say $3/2$?

Comment: I would like to compare the formula given below with yours, but the variables $a$ and $b$ are not defined... (they appear on the right hand side but not on the left hand side of the equation)

Comment: sorry for messing this up - $a$ should be $c$ and $b$ should be $\gamma$

Answer (score 0):

The Meijer-G integral formula recorded [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.34.21.0003.01) implies:
$$\int G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(\begin{matrix}a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_p\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right) \,dz=\frac{z}{\gamma}G_{p+1,q+1}^{m,n+1}\left(\begin{matrix}1-1/\gamma,a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1},\ldots,a_{p}\\ b_1,\ldots,b_m,b_{m+1},\ldots,b_{q},-1/\gamma\end{matrix} , cz^\gamma\right). \tag{1}\label{intgeneral}$$

A simple example with noninteger $\gamma$ is
$$f(z)=G_{0,1}^{1,0}\left(\begin{matrix}.,.\\ 1,.\end{matrix} , \sqrt{z}\right)=e^{-\sqrt{z}} \sqrt{z},\tag{2}\label{fzdef}$$
$$\int f(z)\,dz=-2 e^{-\sqrt{z}} \left(z+2 \sqrt{z}+2\right)+\text{constant},\tag{3}\label{intfz}$$
in agreement with
$$2zG_{1,2}^{1,1}\left(\begin{matrix}-1,.\\ 1,-2\end{matrix} , \sqrt{z}\right)=4-2 e^{-\sqrt{z}} \left(z+2 \sqrt{z}+2\right).\tag{4}\label{intspecial}$$
This holds for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, with a branch cut along the negative real axis.

---

Let me compare with the integral expression in the OP, which for this $\gamma=1/2$ case gives
$$\frac{2z}{\sqrt{z^2}}G_{1,2}^{1,1}\left(\begin{matrix}1,.\\ 3,0\end{matrix} , \sqrt{z}\right)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2}}\left[4-2 e^{-\sqrt{z}} \left(z+2 \sqrt{z}+2\right)\right].\tag{5}\label{OP}$$
This agrees with the correct answer (\ref{intfz}) for $z$ in the first or fourth quadrant of the complex plane, but not in the second or third quadrants.

Comment: The question was "Is it true, that in those two cases the formula is even valid for general $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$?" I don't see how "a somewhat different identity" answers that question.